# Prove A \ (A ∩ B) = (A ∪ B) \ B

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

My question states:
Given sets A and B, show that A \ (A ∩ B) = (A ∪ B) \ B.

This is where I got to before I got stuck:
$$x \; \in \; A \; \setminus \; (A∩B)$$
$$x \; \in \; A \quad and \quad \notin \; (A∩B)$$
$$x \; \in \; A \quad and \quad (x \notin A \; or \; x \notin \; B)$$
$$ x \; \in \; A \quad and \quad x \; \notin \; B$$

Comment: Good work. Now start from the right-hand side and conclude the same.

Comment: If you can't go on, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3376631/show-a-setminus-a-cap-b-a-cup-b-setminus-b#comment6947933_3376631. The same question was asked today.

Comment: In fact, both sets equal A\B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

....

$x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$

($x \in A$ or $x \in B$) and $x\not \in B$

$x \in (A\cup B)\setminus B$.

$A\setminus(A\cap B) \subset (A\cup B)\setminus B$

..........

And if

$x \in (A\cup B) \setminus B$ then

($x\in A$ or $x \in B$) and $x \not \in B$

$x\in A$ and $x \not \in B$

$x\in A$ and ($x \not \in A$ or $x\not \in B$)

$x\in A$ and $x \not \in A\cap B$

$x \in A\setminus (A\cap B)$.

$A\setminus(A\cap B) \supset (A\cup B)\setminus B$

So

$A\setminus(A\cap B) = (A\cup B)\setminus B$