# Show that $A \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \cup B) \setminus B$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Help with missing step in the following proof:

> In order to show that the equality above holds for all A,B , we need
>    to show that (1) $$A \setminus (A \cap B) \subseteq (A \cup B)
>  \setminus B$$  and  (2) $$  (A \cup B) \setminus B \subseteq A
>  \setminus (A \cap B)$$
>
> For a given $x$ , $A \setminus (A \cap B) = \{ x \in A \ | \ x \notin B \} $
>    . Given that $ x \notin (A \cap B) \iff x \notin A \text{ or } x
>  \notin B$ , it follows that: $x$ is in $A$ and $x$ is not in $A$ , or
>    $x$ is not in $B$. Therefore, since $A \cap A^{c} = \emptyset$ , $x$
>   is in A and $x$ is not in $B$.
>
> Conversely, for (2) we have, $$x \in (A \cup B) \ | \ x \notin B$$
>
> Then $x$ is in $A$ or $x$ is in $B$, bt $x$ is not in $B$. Therefore, given that $B \cap B^{c} = \emptyset$ , we have that $x$ is in $A$ but not in $B$.

Two big problems I see:

1. I haven't actually shown that they are subsets of each other, though I can clearly see it. A similar proof presented in lecture, the lecturer translates the "natural language" sentence back into formal set logic showing that they are equal.
2. I was told that starting from the L.H.S, and then starting from R.H.S and arriving at some intermediate conclusion which is the same for both is not a valid proof method. And this seems to be exactly what happened here.

For completeness, here is the kind of proof the lecturer is expecting:

[image]

Comment: The question was already asked today. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3376631/show-a-setminus-a-cap-b-a-cup-b-setminus-b#comment6947933_3376631

Comment: Do you really want to write all that? I mean.... I understand the purpose of writing precise proofs, but in this case drawing two Venn diagrams would be much clearer!

Comment: @GennaroPasquale Thanks for this the "Since x is in A it is in ∪" was the obvious intermediate step that I was missing.

Comment: @b00nheT Thanks for the input, but the prof explicitly mentioned that venn diagrams are not deemed as proofs, just visual aids.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intended answer can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3376631/show-a-setminus-a-cap-b-a-cup-b-setminus-b#comment6947933_3376631). In particular , the intermediate step for (1) is the fact that

> Since x is in $A$ it is in $∪$

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a direct approach is probably easier and more instructive.

$A \setminus (A \cap B) = A \cap (A \cap B)^c = A \cap (A^c \cup B^c) = A \cap B^c $.

$(A \cap B)\setminus B = (A \cap B) \cap B^c = A \cap B^c$.

Comment: Initially I follow this path , but I was trying to replicate the "in-lecture" proof. I much prefer it, I'll hand both in, and see what he says :)

Comment: @SeanCobb: I find the proofs that involve rote steps less prone to mistakes to those that involve reasoning. However your lecturer is king here...

Answer (score 0):

We first select an item $x\in A-(A\cap B)$ (I'm using - as difference because I can't seem to get a \ in this editor.

Notice that $x\in A$, however $x\not \in A\cap B$. As such we can say that $x \in A, x \not \in B$. So $x \in A - B$ and $x\in (A\cup B) - B$, since adding in $B$ will not change that $x$ is in this set. Therefore

$$
A-(A\cap B) \subseteq (A\cup B)-B
$$

Now for the reverse. Assume $y \in (A\cup B)-B$. That means that $y\in A\cup B$ but $y \not \in B$. As such $y \in A$. Since $y\in A, y\not\in B \implies y\not\in A\cap B$ so $y \in A-(A\cap B)$. Therefore

$$
(A\cup B)-B \subseteq A-(A\cap B)
$$

and since both are subsets of each other, then

$$
(A\cup B)-B = A-(A\cap B)
$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but "since adding in  will not change that  is in this set" doesn't seem clear to me without a justification, though I found the intermediate step here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3376631/show-a-setminus-a-cap-b-a-cup-b-setminus-b#comment6947933_3376631

Comment: By that step it just means that $A\subseteq A\cup B$, which is true